# Cannot import python-goose (OSX 10.9)

Tags: python, goose

I am trying to properly set up python-goose in a virtualenv.

**Update**: I nuked python and started with a clean install as outlined [here](http://www.mahdiyusuf.com/post/64878566740/good-clean-python-install-on-mavericks-osx-10-9).

I followed the python-goose [instructions](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) and did:

```
mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages goose
git clone https://github.com/grangier/python-goose.git
cd python-goose
pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py install
```

`pip install -r requirements.txt` fails on `lxml`

Error I get now is:

```
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/me/.virtualenvs/goose/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/me/.virtualenvs/goose/build/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/wg/82j6ndq50tl4m9rjkqszyx8r0000gp/T/pip-c9DtYT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/goose/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in   
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/goose/build/lxml
```

Is there anything I am doing incorrectly or are there any alternative ways I can try to get this working?

Comment: Looks like your problem is still within lxml, from your folder structure I assume you are running OS X, are you using homebrew?

Comment: Hello, yes, running Mavericks and I have homebrew on this machine.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a compression related package, possibly in your Python distribution. Did you build it yourself?

Comment: I am pretty sure I went to www.python.org/download/ and grabbed 2.7 from there.

Comment: I would recommend running Python through homebrew instead. It tends to have all packages needed so you don't have these issues. In this case I think you need both `python` and `libxml2`.

Comment: @Wolph I just installed `python` with brew and `libxml2` is also installed. However, now when I try to install lxml I get a different error (added to answer).

Comment: @emh: that doesn't really help much, I have just executed the install and everything locally and I have no problems so it must be in one of the deps. Where is it dying right now? At the `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: Yes, at the `lxml` stage.

Comment: install the lxml package with pip, i.e. `pip install lxml`, and also make sure that you're using the correct python with `which python`. If it is not `/usr/local/bin/python` then you aren't using the homebrew version of python

Comment: Pseudocubic does raise a good point, are you sure the virtualenv was created with the brew version of python? If it wasn't, you'll have to recreate the virtualenv (trash the old, create a new).

Comment: @Wolph: just trashed it and started over. @pseudocubic outside of my virtualenv `which python` yields: `/usr/local/bin/python` so that looks ok. I tried and was able to install `lxml` globally. When I `workon goose` and run `which python` it yields: `/Users/me/.virtualenvs/goose/bin/python` is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that should be correct :)
Alternatively, you can also enable the global site packages to use the global lxml of course.

Comment: @Wolph, seems like the only option at the moment, but when I run `mkvirtualenv goose --system-site-packages` then `workon goose` and `pip install lxml -I` and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Seems like this error is caused by the latest clang update from Apple that came with Xcode 5.1

> "Update: Did not expect this to get so much attention, but here's more
>   detail: the clang 3.4 Apple is shipping defaults to erroring on
>   unknown flags, but CPython builds modules using the same set of flags
>   it was compiled with originally. The system CPython was compiled with
>   several flags that are unknown by clang, thus causing this problem."

Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22315129/2673189

Again, thanks to Wolph and pseudocubic, you were very helpful.